# Prevent values in first column from re-sorting when sorting other columns using jQuery Tablesorter.js

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to disable sorting on first column in my table while using tablesorter. I want it to always stay the same as in the beggining, even after other columns have been sorted. How can I achieve that?

Example:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
Look at the number column. I want it to always stay the same, while other columns get sorted properly.

Comment: One solution could be to use CSS counter property and pseudo element, see e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/1Lspbovp/1

Comment: I suppose there is a better way to achieve that, but it works, so it's okay with me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can renumber the rows in the first column with a simple loop after sorting.  Give the first TD in each row a class like "rownumber" and then loop through the rownumbers and re-number them.

Your HTML

```
<table class=sortable>
  <tr><th>Row</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
  <tr><td class=rownumber>1</td><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td class=rownumber>2</td><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td class=rownumber>3</td><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td class=rownumber>4</td><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td class=rownumber>5</td><td>Data 1</td><td>Data 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Your jQuery

```
if ($('.sortable').find("tr").size() > 1){  // If table has at least 1 row
  $('.sortable').tablesorter({              // Initialize table sorter
    sortList: [[0,0]]                       // Sort on first column by default
  })
  .bind("sortStart",function() {            // Bind to sortStart
    $('.rownumber').each(function() {       // For each rownumber class
      $(this).html('');                     // Blank out the row number
    });
  })
  .bind("sortEnd",function() {              // Bind to sortEnd
    var newnumber = 1;                      // Start with #1
    $('.rownumber').each(function() {       // For each rownumber class
      $(this).html(newnumber++);            // Re number the rows
    });
  });
}
```